# Is it possible to capture coordinates of mouse clicked on another application e.g calculator and later force a click using code (C#)?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, mouse-hook

I am developing an application using Windows Form (C#). I need to be able to press a button which starts monitoring the location of the next mouse-click inside another application. The coordinates of this click then need to be used to force a click on the same button later in the same application. For testing I am just using a calculator and pressing a key to capture X and Y and then pressing another button to press that key again but it's not working. Any help to figure out what I am doing wrong will be much appreciated.

I have used MouseKeyHook to subscribe to the mouse hook

```
 nuget install MouseKeyHook
```

````
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Point lpPoint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(System.Drawing.Point p);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;

        private struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

//Button click which starts the subscribe
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Subscribe();

        }

        private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_GlobalHook;
public void Subscribe()
        {
            // Note: for the application hook, use the Hook.AppEvents() instead
            m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();

            m_GlobalHook.MouseDownExt += GlobalHookMouseDownExt;
        }

        Point p;
        IntPtr hWnd;
        private void GlobalHookMouseDownExt(object sender, MouseEventExtArgs e)
        {

            if (GetCursorPos(out p))
            {
               IntPtr mainWindow = WindowFromPoint(p);
                hWnd = ChildWindowFromPointEx(mainWindow, p, 0x0000);

                RECT rct = new RECT();
                GetWindowRect(mainWindow, ref rct);
                X = p.X - rct.Left;
                Y = p.Y - rct.Top;
            }

            Unsubscribe();
        }

        public void Unsubscribe()
        {
            m_GlobalHook.MouseDownExt -= GlobalHookMouseDownExt;
            m_GlobalHook.Dispose();
        }


        
        private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN,X, Y);
            
        }
   }
```.
````

Comment: You are sending `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` to a top level parent `HWND` of the app that was clicked on, not to any particular child control that was actually clicked on (like a button). `WindowFromPoint()` doesn't give you a child `HWND`, you need `ChildWindowFromPoint()` for that. For that matter, you should be using `SendInput()` instead of `PostMessage()`

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513)

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau thank you taking time to look at the issue. I tried your suggestion and it still does not click. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot guarantee that the other application(calculator) responds to message you've posted.

In addition, the calculator is a UWP window, you will get an empty `hWnd` with `ChildWindowFromPointEx`. You should use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) to simulate mouse input and ensure that the clicked place is not covered by other windows. Sample in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54072028/10611792

Or use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).